# Cannot get correct return value in sprintf function call

Tags: perl

My problem is that the return value im printing is not being translated into a value.

I have the following code in a test file.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -I/srv/www/jonathan/m/www    
my $var = sprintf("$%.1f lbs",(77*2.20462));
print $var;
```

Its returning: `0.1f` instead of the value i need to see.

What am i doing incorrectly here? I'm a perl newbie.

Comment: Remove that `$` sign, for: `sprintf("%.1f lbs", ...)`. See [`sprintf`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html).

Comment: what are you trying to print? The `$` needs an argument position before it, but you don't specify which argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perl uses **dolar($)** symbol to declare a scalar variable, you need to remove the `$` symbol from the sprintf.

corrected code

```
my $var = sprintf("%.1f lbs",(77*2.20462));
print $var;
```

output

```
169.8 lbs
```

Comment: Changing the double-quotes to single-quotes is simpler and doesn't change the output.

Comment: Its one of the way to avoid `$` symbol as variable and  I am not sure about the output requirement .I believe the questioner was interested about the value only.

Comment: You might be right, as he accepted your answer. But you were guessing. I'd always assume that the person asking the question knows what output they want and would give an answer that reproduces the original output over one that doesn't.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that Perl interprets "$%.1f" as the variable `$%` followed by ".1f". `$%` is a special Perl variable containing "The current page number of the currently selected output channel" (see [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html)) and that has the value 0, so what gets printed is the string "0.1f".

There are a few ways round this.

You can remove the dollar sign: `sprintf("%.1f lbs",(77*2.20462))`. But that changes the string that you display.

You can escape the dollar to tell Perl that it's not special: `sprintf("\$%.1f lbs",(77*2.20462))`.

But I think there's a better solution. Perl treats dollar signs as special characters in double-quoted strings. But there's no reason for your string to be double-quoted. So just change your format string to use single quotes: `sprintf('$%.1f lbs',(77*2.20462))`.

That last one is the solution I'd use.